# Proving that $\cos(2\pi/n)$ is algebraic

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I want to prove this without using any of the properties about the field of algebraic numbers (specifically that it is one). Essentially I just want to find a polynomial for which $\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}$ is a root.

I know roots of unity and De Moivre's theorem is clearly going to be important here but I just can't see how to actually construct the polynomial from these facts.

Comment: The fast fourier transform together with higher frequencies are polynomials in lower frequencies should be enough to write any of them as radicals of polynomials in the other frequencies. And radicals of polynomials are of course algebraic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you familiar with the Chebyshev polynomials $T_n$ ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials))? One property is that
$$T_n(\cos(\theta))=\cos(n\theta)$$
(see [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Trigonometric_definition)). Thus
$$T_n(\cos(\tfrac{2\pi}{n}))=\cos(2\pi)=1$$
and therefore an example of a polynomial with $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{n})$ as a root is $T_n-1$.

Comment: I was not aware of these, I will read into them thank you!

Answer (score 14):

We know $\cos(2\pi/n)+i\sin(2\pi/n)$ is algebraic ($n$th root of unity).  And the complex conjugate of algebraic is algebraic (in fact it's just another $n$th root of unity), so add it to its conjugate because also the sum of two algebraics is algebraic. Then divide by two.

Comment: I understand this but I wish to prove that it is algebraic without using the property that algebraic numbers are a field. That is, without assuming the sum or product of two algebraic numbers is algebraic.

Comment: This uses the fact that the set of algebaics is closed under addition (and division by two). This is maybe too much §of the properties of the field of algebraic numbers (specifically thatit is a flied)"

Comment: OK sorry, guess this answer doesn't fit the desired parameters.

Answer (score 12):

Let $\theta=\frac{2\pi}{n}$. By De Moivre's formula we have
$$ (\cos \theta + i\sin\theta)^n = \cos n\theta + i\sin n\theta = 1 $$

Expand the left-hand side using the binomial theorem!

Every other term of the expansion contains a $\pm i$ and an *odd* power of $\sin\theta$; we know these terms cancel out because the imaginary part of the right-hand side is zero.

If we remove all those, what is left is *real* terms with only *even* powers of $\sin \theta$. Substitute $(\sin\theta)^{2n} = (1-\cos^2\theta)^n$. Now you have a polynomial identity with integer coefficients in $\cos \theta$ -- in other words, an integer polynomial with $\cos\theta$ as root. Thus $\cos\theta$ is algebraic.

[This is actually one way to derive the Chebyshev polynomials].

Comment: (+1) I was working on the same idea and didn't see that you had outlined the same idea in the meantime.

Answer (score 9):

[Euler's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) implies
$$
\left[\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)\right]^n=1\tag{1}
$$
The [Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) says
$$
\begin{align}
1
&=\sum_{k=0}^ni^k\binom{n}{k}\cos^{n-k}\!\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)\sin^k\!\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n}{2k}\cos^{n-2k}\!\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)\sin^{2k}\!\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)\\
&+i\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n}{2k+1}\cos^{n-2k-1}\!\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)\sin^{2k+1}\!\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Looking at the real part of $(2)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
1
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n}{2k}\cos^{n-2k}\!\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)\sin^{2k}\!\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n}{2k}\cos^{n-2k}\!\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)\left[1-\cos^2\!\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)\right]^k\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(-1)^m\cos^{n-2m}\!\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)\sum_{k=m}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}\binom{k}{m}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Equation $(3)$ gives a polynomial equation whose root is $\cos\!\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)$. Furthermore, the coefficient of $\cos^n\!\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)$ is $2^{n-1}$, which implies that $2\cos\!\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)$ is an algebraic integer. This polynomial also has a root of $1$, so it is reducible.

---

**Example:** Using $n=7$ in $(3)$, we have that $\cos\!\left(\frac{2\pi}7\right)$ satisfies
$$
64x^7-112x^5+56x^3-7x-1=0\tag{4}
$$
Note that $1$ is also a root of $(4)$.

Answer (score 1):

The fourier transform together with higher frequencies are polynomials in lower frequencies should be enough to write any of them as radicals of polynomials in the other frequencies. And of course that radicals of polynomials are algebraic.