# Prove that $\sin ^{-1} 1 $ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Prove or disprove  the following :

> $1.\sin ^{-1}  1 $ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$
>
> $2.\cos (\frac{\pi}{17})$ is
> algebraic over $\mathbb Q$

As suggested by @Andre ,for the 2nd one

$(\cos (\frac{\pi}{17})+i\sin (\frac{\pi}{17}))^{17}=-1$ (De Moivre's Theorem)
Expanding the L.H.S binomially and separating the real and imaginary parts and equating them to the R.H.S. we get a polynomial whose root is $\cos (\frac{\pi}{17})$

Is the above solution correct?

How should I proceed here? I am not getting any hints to work this one out

Comment: You probably know what $\sin^{-1} 1$ is (I assume that you mean $\arcsin 1$).  For the second, think about $(\cos(\pi/17)\pm i\sin(\pi/17))^{17}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas;I did the second one ;please check

Comment: Yes, your method for the second is correct. But you need to add some detail. When we expand, the real part gives $\cos^{17} \theta-\binom{17}{2}\cos^{15}\theta\sin^2\theta+\cdots=-1$. There will be various **even** powers of $\sin\theta$. Replace $\sin^2\theta$ everywhere by $1-\cos^2\theta$.

Comment: Alternately, use the hint to show that $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta-i\sin\theta$ are both algebraic. Then use the fact that $\cos\theta$ is half the sum of these, and the sum of two algebraics is algebraic. The disadvantage of this method is that we have to use the non-trivial result that the sum of two algebraics is algebraic. Your suggested method is "closer to the ground."

Comment: For an elementary solution see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305151/proving-that-cos2-pi-n-is-algebraic).

Comment: Thank you very much @AndréNicolas

Comment: @AndréNicolas; you did not say what to do with $\sin ^{-1} 1$

Comment: @learnmore:  You are welcome. For the first question, we have $\sin^{-1}(1)=\pi/2$. It is a standard result that $\pi$ is transcendental (not algebraic). From this it follows that $\pi/2$ is not algebraic. You would not be expected to *prove* that $\pi$ is transcendental, the proof is difficult. It is enough to quote the result, which is due to Lindemann.

Comment: Okay I got that @AndréNicolas